# How to works Home android default button in my own Android Apps? using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-homebutton, home-button

I want to pause my apps music when I click my home button. But I can't access my mobile home button `onclick` event. How can I access androids default home button event when my apps are runing?

Answer (score 1):

`onPause()` gets called you press the home button. So you can pause your music there.